# Can I have multiple .svc files in one virtual directory under IIS in WCF?

Tags: wcf

Can I have multiple .svc files in one virtual directory under IIS in WCF? If so how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have two service contracts and in the `web.config` section you need to have the two services registered:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="YourNamespace.Service1" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
            <endpoint 
                address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"           
                contract="Yournamespace.IService1" />
        </service>
        <service name="YourNamespace.Service2" 
                 behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
            <endpoint 
                address="" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"           
                contract="Yournamespace.IService2" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then you could have two `.svc` files for each of your services.