# what are the best practices in hosting more than one wcf servicehosts (.svc files) in IIS 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have three type of wcf services developped and for which i have created three .svc files like this:

service1.svc
service2.svc
service3.svc

in an asp.net website project.

So how to host these services on the IIS 7?

and what are the best practices in hosting more than one services (.svc) files.?

i saw this link:

[Can I have multiple .svc files in one virtual directory under IIS in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880465/can-i-have-multiple-svc-files-in-one-virtual-directory-under-iis-in-wcf)

which i know already, so is this the only best practise available.? or i am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You will need one .svc file to instantiate the `ServiceHost` for each specific webservice.
However, you will have to look into the IIS specific features like 'Health monitoring', 'Process recycling' etc.

When configurating you services, use relative addressing (i.e. when you expose multiple enpoints using one .svc).

Answer (score 0):

You can check on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) how to host WCF Service on IIS using SVC file.

> what are the best practices in hosting more than one services (.svc)
>   files.?

Yes, you can host more than one service on IIS. But If you have **N services** you need to have **N svc files** and **N service contracts** on your **web.config**.

Comment: and my url looks like http://servername/service1.svc and http://servername/service2.svc. but i dont like that .svc coming in the url, is there any option to remove that .svc thing from the url?

Comment: You can change that if you are hosting your service within ASP.net application. You just need to configure a route for each WCF service. Check Scott Guthrie's blog talking about that http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx